# Firebase Analytics incorrect new users, active users (higher than Adjust and Play Console in 5 times every day)

Tags: android, firebase, events, google-bigquery, google-play

Hello stackoverflow community!
I have Android app and I'm using for Analytics - Firebase and Adjust.
Based on analysis I'm discovering that on daily comparison instruments analytics - Firebase showing in 7 times more active users per day and in 4 times more first time visitors per day than Adjust or Play Console. And it's looks creepy. I asked developer check Firebase SDK - but it works correct.

Also I connected Firebase to GA4 and streaming data to Bigquery. Based on raw data - situation looks same. Here is query in bigquery for raw data calculation by user id's (daily active users).

```
SELECT 
      event_date, 
      count(distinct user_pseudo_id), 
      count(distinct device.advertising_id) 
FROM `*.events_2023*` 
WHERE 
      device.operating_system = 'Android' 
   AND 
      event_name = 'user_engagement'
   AND 
      is_active_user is true

GROUP BY event_date
```

So my main question how this could be? What's wrong with Firebase setup and why it showing so huge incorrect data?